# Navigation argument Double error : Can't escape identifier `0.0` because it contains illegal characters

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

Error when setting defaultValue for Double in Navigation graph argument.

```
 <argument
            android:name="lat"
            app:argType="java.lang.Double"
            android:defaultValue="0.0"
            />
        <argument
            android:name="lon"
            app:argType="kotlin.Double"
            android:defaultValue="0.0"
            />
```

I hae tried both `java.lang.Double` and `kotlin.Double` with safe args plugin.

How can I pass a Double argument with default value?

Comment: Did you also try the primitive `double` instead of `java.lang.Double`? Maybe it doesn't work with boxing? But that's just a guess.

Comment: double is not supported. see https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Comment: But you can pass java.lang.Double without default value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safe Args currently does not support decimal type. If you don't need high precision but want to send through a decimal value (you can find differences between float and decimal [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#floating-point-types)), you should just use a float. You can find supported argument types [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data).

If you really need high precision, you will need to get some workarounds like sending it through as a string or breaking the whole number and the decimal part into two integer values (so for 12.43, you will send in 12 as one variable and 43 as another).

Answer (score 6):

You can create a Serializable class and store lat, long in that and pass an object of that class as type "custom serializable" in Navigation Arguments.

Here is a sample,

Kotlin

```
data class LatLong(
    var lat: Double = 0.0,
    var long: Double = 0.0
) : Serializable
```

Navigation Graph:

```
<argument
        android:name="LatLong"
        app:argType="com.example.models.LatLong" />
```